# What is the difference between many cursor-word-related commands in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am customizing cursor-word-related commands with new keybindings. And there are many [cursor-word-related commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB9Y0.png) in VS code. I know the command with `Part` has something to do with `_` in words in a VS Code GitHub issue. But what is the difference between all the other commands? Say, what is the difference between `cursorWordLeft` and `cursorWordStartLeft`?

I have been googling for a while, but I cannot find docs or anything official on this topic. And it is really timing-consuming to test out every command. So is there anything on this topic that I can look into?

Also, which two commands correspond to the operation we normally do with `Ctrl+Right` and `Ctrl+Left` on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer your question partially. The difference between `cursorWord` vs `cursorWordStart` is that `cursorWord` is what the VSCode developer team created for the **VSCode editor** (they can make it work however they want). While `cursorWordStart` is essentially what **Visual Studio IDE** uses and it was added to VSCode, made to work exactly the same (so they don't touch it).

My answer is expanded upon what Alex Dima posted on GitHub (a Microsoft developer working on VSCode). I don't think it gets much more official than that. [Source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/67165#issuecomment-514952371)